# How to evaluate this indefinite integral by only using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate $$\int \sqrt{\frac x{x-1}}dx?$$
I am trying to evaluate this integral by only using trigonometric substitution. I am thinking of substituting $x=\sec^2\theta$. Therefore, the above integral will become $$2\int\sqrt{\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta}}\sec^2\theta\tan\theta d\theta.$$ Therefore, after this step, we can write the above integral as $$2 \int \sqrt{\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta}\sec^2\theta\tan\theta d\theta.$$
Now here one interesting fact which I noticed is that we can't write $\sqrt{\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta}=|\operatorname{cosec}\theta|$. The only reason for this is that we can't write $|\operatorname{cosec}\theta|=\operatorname{cosec}\theta$ because $|\operatorname{cosec}\theta|=\operatorname{cosec}\theta$ only when $\operatorname{cosec}\theta>0$. But we know that the range of $\operatorname{cosec}\theta$ is $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$. And $\operatorname{cosec}\theta>0$ means $\operatorname{cosec}\theta\in(0,1]\cup[1,\infty)$. Therefore, $|\operatorname{cosec}\theta|\ne\operatorname{cosec}\theta$. Similarly $|\operatorname{cosec}\theta|\neq-\operatorname{cosec}\theta$ and also $|\operatorname{cosec}\theta|\ne0$. Therefore I am facing problem in integrating $$2\int\sqrt{\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta}\sec^2\theta\tan\theta d\theta.$$
Please help me out with this integral.

Comment: Maybe $|\csc\theta|=sgn(\theta)\csc\theta$ can be written.

Comment: You did well. Don't worry about the issue. Simply go ahead and you will get the right result. See my answer for details.

Comment: There seems to be a really great lack of understanding with the part of inequalities and moduli. So much so that I would recommend you start to learn the basics from the high school level. sec x > 0 does not imply what you said. It just means we removed the negative range of sec x. Tell me, a > 0 and a > 1 implies a > 1 or a > 0. According to you, it means a > 0 which is obviously incorrect and a > 1 is a stronger inequality.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to render directly

$u=\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{x-1}}$

Then

$u^2=\dfrac{x}{x-1}$

$xu^2-u^2=x$

$x=\dfrac{u^2}{u^2-1}$

Then

$dx=-\dfrac{2u}{(u^2-1)^2}du$

So the full integrand is rendered as

$u dx=-\dfrac{2u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}du$

which should be handled by partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}} $, then $x=\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=1+\frac{1}{u^2-1} $ and $d x=d\left(\frac{1}{u^2-1}\right)$.

By integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int u d\left(\frac{1}{u^2-1}\right) \\
& =\frac{u}{u^2-1}-\int \frac{1}{u^2-1} d u \\
& =\frac{u}{u^2-1}-\frac12\ln \left|\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right|+C\\&=(x-1) \sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}} +\frac12\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}+1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}-1}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$
\begin{aligned}
&
\end{aligned}

Comment: Would you mind to make a double check ? I guess there is an error in your expression regarding $\int \frac{1}{u^2-1} du$.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my error.  Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You did well by setting $x=\sec^2\theta$ and already got

$\qquad I=\int \sqrt{\frac x{x-1}}dx=2\int \sqrt{\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta}\sec^2\theta\tan\theta d\theta$.

Note that $x$ must be greater than $1$, otherwise the integrand will NOT be a real number. Now simply continue to go ahead without your worry to get

$\qquad I=2\int cosec\ \theta\sec^2\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta=2\int sec^3\theta\ d\theta$.

This will lead to

$\qquad I=\frac{sin\theta}{cos^2\theta}+ln(\frac{1+sin\theta}{cos\theta})+c$,

where $c$ is any constant. Since $\theta=arcsec(\sqrt{x})$, so we have

$\qquad sin\theta=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}$, $cos\theta=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Substituting these into the expression of $I$ finally yields

$\qquad I=\sqrt{x(x-1)}+ln(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1})+c$.

The correctness of this final expression can be verified by deriving the derivative $\frac{dI}{dx}$ to see that indeed $\frac{dI}{dx}$ equals the original integrand.

Comment: You can ask anybody who doesn't even study mathematics in a great depth, they all know the root cannot be negative and you interpreting it as you wish is not something that matters. $\sqrt {x^2}$ was defined to be |x|. Kindly start reading a bit if you have doubt in such basic things. And also, OP had a problem in the fact that we cannot use |cosec theta| = cosec theta because cosec theta can be negative (do you know moduli operator? It doesn't look like it based on what you are saying)