# How to integrate $\int \sqrt{\sec^{2}x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to integrate $$\int \sqrt{\sec^{2}x}dx$$ ? Let me first show my approach. My approach is $$\int \sqrt{\sec^{2}x}dx$$=$$\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x}}dx$$=$$\int \sqrt{\frac{2}{2(\cos^{2}x)}}dx$$ = $$\int \sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\cos(2x)}}dx$$ = $$\int\sqrt{\frac{2(1-\cos(2x))}{(1+\cos(2x))(1-\cos(2x))}}dx$$ = $$\int \sqrt{\frac{2(1-\cos(2x))}{1-\cos^{2}(2x)}}dx$$ = $$\int \sqrt{\frac{2(1-\cos(2x))}{\sin^{2}(2x)}}dx$$ = $$\int \sqrt{2cosec^{2}(2x)-2cosec(2x)\cot(2x)}dx$$. But after this step I can't proceed further. Also I searched the solution of this integral in Wolfram Alpha but haven't understood their way of solution. They have considered $$\int \sqrt{\sec^{2}(x)}dx=\int \sec(x)dx$$. But I haven't understood why they have considered $\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}=\sec(x)$. Because $\sqrt{\sec^{2}(x)}=\sec(x)$ only when $\sec(x)>0$. But we know that the range of $\sec(x)$ is $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$ and $\sec(x)>0$ implies $\sec(x)\in(0,1]\cup[1,\infty)$. So, I don't think that we can consider$\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}=\sec(x)$. So, please help me out with this integral.

Comment: $\sqrt{\sec^2x} = |\sec x|$, so you can integrate $\pm \sec x$ to get answers for different intervals.

Comment: The best approach is to treat the $\sec x < 0$ case as a separate integration from the $\sec x>0$ case. So you **do** consider $\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}=\sec(x)$. Then you consider $\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}=-\sec(x)$. And that covers both cases.

Comment: Why did Wolfram Alpha consider $\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}=\sec(x)$?  Because, by default, WA considers the complex variable case.  For $x$ a complex variable, $\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}=|\sec(x)|$ is **simply wrong**.  (The LHS is an analytic functoin, but the RHS is not.)

Comment: Could it not be the simple $\pm  \log( \tan x +\ \sec x)$?

Comment: Yes you are correct @GEdgar. I made that mistake there.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int{\sec\left(x\right)\,\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sec\left(x\right)\right)}{\;\mathrm{d}x}$$

By multiplication
$$\frac{\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)}{\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)}$$

$$\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sec\left(x\right)\right)\int{\dfrac{\sec\left(x\right)\,\tan\left(x\right)+\sec^{2}\left(x\right)}{\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}x}$$

Substitution
\begin{gathered}\;u=\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)&\\\;\mathrm{d}u=\left(\sec\left(x\right)\,\tan\left(x\right)+\sec^{2}\left(x\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x&\end{gathered}

$$\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sec\left(x\right)\right)\int{\dfrac{1}{u}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$

Integral table
$$\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sec\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\ln\left(\left|u\right|\right)=\ln\left(\left|u\right|\right)\,\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sec\left(x\right)\right)$$

Rewriting
$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|u\right|\right)\,\left|\sec\left(x\right)\right|}{\sec\left(x\right)}$$

Substitute back

$$\dfrac{\left|\sec\left(x\right)\right|\,\ln\left(\left|\tan\left(x\right)+\sec\left(x\right)\right|\right)}{\sec\left(x\right)}$$

Comment: Not sure that you can take $\text{sgn} \,\text{sec}(x)$ out of the integral...

Comment: sgn sec(x) will depend on sec(x) (and thus x). So you cannot take it out of the integral sign

Comment: @HamLemon The domain of the integral is disconnected and the integral cannot be defined across two disconnected pieces. It can only be integrated within one connected piece. Within each connected piece, the sign of $sec(x)$ is constant. So whether the person writing this answer understood all that or not, you can justify taking $\operatorname{sgn}(\sec(x))$ out of the integral.

Comment: Ok yeah, that's true. I understand it now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> $\int \sqrt{\sec^{2}x}dx$

Solution:
$$\int \sqrt{\sec^{2}x}dx{=\int \frac{\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}\cdot\sec x}{\sec x}dx\\=\frac{\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}}{\sec x}\int \sec x dx-\int\left[\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}}{\sec x}\right)\int \sec x dx\right]+c\quad (IBP)\\
=\frac{\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}}{\sec x}\int \sec x dx+c \quad \left[\because \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}}{\sec x}\right)=0\right]\\
=\frac{\sqrt{\sec^{2}x}}{\sec x}\ln|\sec x +\tan x|+c}$$

for more generalization see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828032/1213102).

Answer (score 1):

To put all of the claims in the answers into perspective, here is the graph of
$y = \sqrt{\sec^2(x)}$ if we consider only real $x$:

[image]

The domain of the function consists of an infinite number of disconnected pieces. Within each piece, which is an open interval from $-\frac\pi2 + n\pi$ to $\frac\pi2 + n\pi$ for some integer $n$, the function $f(x) = \sqrt{\sec^2(x)}$ is continuous and integrable.

Any formula for the integral should result in a function something like the function added to the graph below, in addition to $y = \sqrt{\sec^2(x)}$ (which is shown for reference).

[image]

That is, the integral consists of disconnected branches, each of which approaches $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $-\frac\pi2 + n\pi$ and approaches $\infty$ as $x$ goes to $\frac\pi2 + n\pi$ for whichever integer $n$ applies to that branch.
Moreover, every branch has its own constant of integration,
but there is no way to make two of these branches into one continuous function.

You may notice that the branches of the integral on intervals where $\sec(x)$ is positive are identical to the integral of $\sec(x)$, whereas branches on intervals where $\sec(x)$ is negative are identical to the integral of $-\sec(x)$,
which is a simple consequence of the fact that $\sqrt{\sec^2(x)}$ is equal to either $\sec(x)$ or $-\sec(x)$ depending on which connected part of the domain of $\sec(x)$ we find $x$ in.

A general formula for the integral is
$$
\int \sqrt{\sec^2(x)}\,\mathrm dx =
\operatorname{sgn}(\sec(x)) \log(\lvert\tan(x)+\sec(x)\rvert) + C_n,
$$
where $C_n$ is a constant of integration defined separately for each
interval $\left(-\frac\pi2 + n\pi, \frac\pi2 + n\pi\right)$.
This is a simple consequence of the fact that the function we are integrating is just like the secant function except that the sign of the function value is reversed on some of the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very standard trick to evaluate the integral of the $\sec$ function.

Suppose that $\sec(x) > 0$. Then we may deduce that:
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{\sec^{2}(x)}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\sec(x)\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\cos(x)}\\\\
& = \int\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^{2}(x)}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int\frac{\cos(x)}{1 - \sin^{2}(x)}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(\sin(x))}{1 - \sin^{2}(x)}
\end{align*}

where you can apply the substitution $u = \sin(x)$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I do not think he has asked how to calculate the integral of sec x, I am pretty sure he knows how to do that. He is probably having trouble in removing the sec x out of the root and so wants to solve it inside the root only.

Comment: Yes I know how to integrate $\sec(x)$. But I am facing problem in integrating $\int \sqrt{\sec^{2}(x)}dx$.

Comment: You are correct @Atila Correia. But what for $\sec(x)<0$? You also have to consider that case.

Answer (score -2):

The point of indefinite integrals has usually been to evaluate definite integrals, and if that's the case here, we can very clearly see that someone cannot ask you a definite integral where the limits are such that $\sec x$ changes sign because the only way it does change sign is by going from $\infty \rightarrow - \infty$ or vice versa. While you may argue that due to symmetry, we can calculate area under graph for the given limits (like from $\frac{\pi}{4} \rightarrow \frac{3\pi}{4}$ can be said to be zero), but the integral will become undefined/indeterminate (you can check in any good calculator like [Wolfram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QODV.jpg) or [Desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2le4g.jpg))

If you have no limits, then we have no other options but to split the integral into two cases (only two cases : one where sec x is negative over the whole interval of integration and one where it is positive over the whole interval of integration because we have established that sec x cannot change sign in or at the boundary of the the interval). When sec x is positive, the integral is simply $ln (|\sec x + \tan x|)$. But when sec x is negative,   $\sqrt{\sec^2 x} = - \sec x$ and integrate like before to get -$ln (|\sec x + \tan x|)$. This is indeed correct and rather [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5BSquare%5BSec%5Bx%5D%5D%5D%2Cx%5D) did return a [single (closed form) answer when I checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIu15.jpg)

Comment: Looking at the graph Wolfram Alpha drew for you, if you were to integrate from $0$ to $\pi$ then you have an infinite increase in the real part between $0$ and $\pi/2$ and then another infinite increase between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$. So you can't even do a Cauchy principal value integral.

Comment: Sorry, but I do  not know what a cauchy principal value integral is. I will try and understand this by looking at sources from the web. Thank you for your input

Comment: No one can write $\sqrt{\sec^{2}(x)}=sgn(\sec(x))\sec(x)$. Because we know that $sgn(x)=0$ when $x=0$. But we know that $\sec(x)\neq0$. Therefore $sgn(\sec(x))$ is not possible.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti I don't know why you posted this comment under this answer, which does not mention $\operatorname{sgn}(\sec(x))$, but you are mistaken. The function $x\mapsto\operatorname{sgn}(\sec(x))$ is perfectly well defined for all $x$ where $\sec(x)$ is defined and it produces either $1$ or $-1$ as a value, never zero, precisely **because** $\sec(x)$ is never zero.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti To put it another way, it is just as valid to write $\operatorname{sgn}(\sec(x))$ as it is to write $\sqrt{\sec^2(x)}$ even though we know that $\sqrt x=0$ when $x=0$ and that $\sec(x)\neq0$. I mean, you didn't object to the **square root** function, but you object to the sign function?

Comment: Actually the definition of $sgn$ function is $sgn(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$, when $x\neq 0$ and $0$ when $x=0$. Similarly $sgn(\sec(x))=\frac{|\sec(x)|}{\sec(x)}$, when $\sec(x)\neq 0$ and $0$ when $\sec(x)=0$. But the fact is that $\sec(x)$ is never equal to $0$.

Comment: Look at what you are saying, you keep giving these arguments as if we cannot write f(g(x)) if the range of g(x) is an interval of the domain of f(x). If sgn(x) = 0 for x = 0, and sec x does not ever become 0, why do you care about that and justify using this fact that we cannot use sgn(sec x)? It is not necessary for sec x to contain full domain of sgn(x) in its range, it is only necessary for the range of sec x to not be more than the domain of sgn(x).

Comment: Even in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815229/how-to-evaluate-this-indefinite-integral-by-only-using-trigonometric-substitutio) of yours you stated |cosec x| cannot be used because cosec x does not achieve any value $\in(-1,1)$. This is why I am saying, you show a very clear lack of understanding basic maths so you should really revisit some old chapters about domains and composite functions from probably 7th - 8th grade and also, stop arguing with people online.